# Time taken by the pendulum to complete one oscillation with initial angle $ \theta = 90° $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, differential-equations

The question that I have is pretty much the question in the image below. The question was given to my class (11th grade) by our physics teacher as a challenge problem. I think this is important to mention as because we are still high school students we are not expected to have any advanced knowledge of mathematics and physics. Just basic calculus and the easy differential equations ( the ones which can be solved easily using seperation of variables).

[image]

We are asked to compare the time taken by ball A and ball B, and the distance covered by them.

I spent hours trying to solve it, but I just couldn’t solve the first part of it. It was easy to calculate the distance covered by both the balls, it would be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for ball A and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2} ln \left( \sqrt{2} + 1 \right)$ for ball B. To calculate the distance covered by ball B I just found the trajectory equation of the parabola, and computed the arclength by integration. I was also able to find the time taken by ball B. To do this I just used conservation of energy to find initial and final velocities and then used $ v = u + gt $ and solved for time. The time taken was, $ \sqrt{ \frac{2}{g} } \left( \sqrt{2} + 1 \right) $ So my first question is, are these values correct ?

Now, I can’t really calculate the time period for ball A. Because it is a pendulum, my first thought was to use the familiar time period equation $ T = 2 \pi \sqrt{ \frac{l}{g} } $ but this is only valid for small angles as after about 10° the error starts to get pretty significant. That’s why, using this approach is not really going to give us a very good answer. I searched online but the only approach I could find was using the above equation.

So I tried to solve the differential equation of the pendulum exactly. Because I don’t really have any experience solving such complex differential equations, I didn’t quite realise how difficult the task was, but I eventually found a YouTube video of the exact solution to it, which included an elliptical integral of the first kind. I then solved it using WolframAlpha and got the time period taken for $ \frac{1}{4} $ th oscillation by ball A to be approximately 0.72 s. Is this correct ?

How can we solve this using basic mathematics and physics ? Because as I mentioned earlier, we are not supposed to know how to solve such complex equations, and we certainly were not meant to use a calculator.

Can you please share your solution ? Also, is my solution to other part of this question correct ? Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: The time for ball B is the time to fall 1 m with acceleration g and no initial velocity. Your value is wrong.

Comment: @nasu The ball A strikes the ball B in an elastic collision, so the velocity of ball A would be transferred to ball B. So ball B would have intial velocity equal to the final velocity of ball A. Final velocity of A can be calculated easily using conservation of energy to be, $ U_i + K_i = U_f + K_f $ where gravitational potential energy is taken with repsect to the table. So, $ mg + 0 = 0 + \frac{1}{2} mv^2 $ solving gives, $ V_{a,final} = V_{b,initial} = \sqrt{2g} $

Comment: Homework Qs are generally taken negatively on this site, you may want to edit it

Comment: ii. You can answer it is b directly. The $A$ is constrained to move in a circle, so the energy it gains from gravity is split into horizontal and vertical component. When A hits B, it gives the maximum velocity one can attain from gravity in the first instant itself. B keeps the velocity throughout it's whole journey and hence travels more distance

Comment: @Srinidhi kabra The ball B has no vertical initial velocity. So its vertical motion is free fall with zero initial velocity. The final velocity you calculate in the OP is the total velocity which has both horizontal and vertical components. Aplying the law of motion to this is wrong. The acceleration is equal to g only for the vertical component. Have you studied the proljectile motion?

Comment: @Srinidhi kabra The velocity you show in your OP nd in the comment is horizontal. It has nothing to do with the vertical motion.

Comment: You don't need the period of the pendulum's motion. You just need to compare the teo motion, not to find specific values.

Comment: Yes, I realise now that I made a really silly mistake. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: How will i compare them though ? I thought of that, but just could not find a way to compare them.I calculate the value of $ t_B = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{g}} $

Comment: Can you please share your solution @nasu ?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos The answer would not be ball B for the second question. We need to find the the total distance travelled by the balls on their respective trajectories. If you were to find the equation of the parabola for ball B and then integrate it to find the arclength then you would get the same answer as mine. So you can see that ball A would travel larger distance than ball B.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by distance. I took it as how much horizontal gap is covered

Comment: There is an ambiguity in part ii.   I interpret it as asking for the vector length between the starting point of B and the point at which it hits the ground.  This is considerably less than the path length it takes to get there (which is a slightly more difficult calculation)

Comment: I am amazed. Are you sure that is the case? @Srinidhikabra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just think about the vertical motion. They both fall for 1m. The ball B has acceleration g for the full duration of the vertical motion. The ball A starts with g and then the vertical component of the acceleration decreases to zero. Which one takes more time?

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don’t get it. Can you just tell me the answer and you solved it ?

Comment: @Srinidhikabra  what he's hinting is that you need to go back to the fundamental equation for pendulum motion, and solve the integral of the vector force value due to gravity.

Comment: I suppose, problem is qualitative not quantitative. Answer of nasu doesn't require calculation at all. Average acceleration of A is less, initial velocity of both balls is zero, distance is the same, then time of A is ...

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much. I should’ve focused more on what the problem was actually describing rather than diving straight into computations.

Comment: You don't have to solve any integral. Or any other euqation. Just to think and understand the characteristics of the two motions.

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Nasu has answered your question. Just for reference, I did a numeric simulation for your pendulum (110 steps on a spreadsheet) and found that the bob swings down from the horizontal in just over 0.6 seconds. (Compare with 0.4518 s for the projectile.)(assuming g = 9.8 m/s/s.)

Comment: By using the first three terms in the series expansion of the period for large amplitude I've got 0.59 s, so it is close to your numeric simulation which may be closer to the actual value.